# Firebase with ReactJs: TypeError: this.Ref.orderBy is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ecmascript-6

Hello i'm tying to query specific data from my Firebase by using the `oderBy` and the `equalTo` function, but it gives me this error, does anybody know what i'm doing wrong ?

```
constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.Ref = firebase.database().ref().child('app').child('cards');
     }

     componentWillReceiveProps (){
       this.Ref.orderBy('address').equalTo(this.props.city)
          .on('child_added', snap => {
            console.log(snap)
          })
     }
```

Comment: What does `console.log(this.Ref)` return?

Comment: The method is `orderByChild`: `this.Ref.orderByChild('address').equalTo(this.props.city)`

Comment: thank you !! im sry for this stupid mistake, but it seems there is not that much of ReactJs + Firebase on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you use this.state in the constructor? You'd be more closely to the react default model and avoid poss. hidden caveats